# custom footer on title page using \maketitle and book document class

Tags: header-footer, titles, fancyhdr

I'm trying to add a custom footer to the title page of my thesis, in order to insert some text that is required by my university. I'm using `fancyhdr` to do so. However, the footer appears on the second page and not the first. How can I fix this?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\fancypagestyle{titlepagestyle}
{
   \fancyhf{}
   \fancyfoot[C]{\emph{This text needs to appear on the title page}}
   \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0 mm}
}

\pagestyle{plain} 

\begin{document}

\title{The title}

\author{The author}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{titlepagestyle}


\mainmatter

\chapter{The chapter heading}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

I've also tried using adding a footnote instead of using `fancyhdr`, with the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can patch the `\maketitle` like

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\patchcmd{\maketitle}
  {\end{titlepage}}
  {\thispagestyle{titlepagestyle}\end{titlepage}}
  {}{}
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\patchcmd{\maketitle}
  {\end{titlepage}}
  {\thispagestyle{titlepagestyle}\end{titlepage}}
  {}{}

\fancypagestyle{titlepagestyle}
{
   \fancyhf{}
   \fancyfoot[C]{\emph{This text needs to appear on the title page}}
   \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0 mm}
}

\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\title{The title}

\author{The author}
%\thispagestyle{titlepagestyle}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\mainmatter

\chapter{The chapter heading}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You really don't have to define a new page style for that: the `titling` package is here for customising title pages. I used the `geometry` package with option `showframe`to help visualise the result:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}
\title{The title}
\author{The author}
\predate{\centering}
\postdate{\vfill\hfill\emph{This text needs to appear on the title page}\hfill}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\mainmatter

\chapter{The chapter heading}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A second alternative without patching is use of local footnote without numbering.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\fancypagestyle{titlepagestyle}
{
   \fancyhf{}
   \fancyfoot[C]{}%\emph{This text needs to appear on the title page}}
   \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0 mm}
}


\pagestyle{plain}     
\begin{document}

\begingroup
\title{The title}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{}
\author{The author
\footnote{\hspace{2cm}
This text needs to appear on the title page}}
\maketitle
\endgroup

\thispagestyle{titlepagestyle}
\mainmatter

\chapter{The chapter heading}

adadasdf\footnote{another footnote}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```