# How to use fancyhdr and \maketitle concurrently

Tags: titles, fancyhdr

I'm trying to use fancy header and \maketitle concurrently. This causes a problem because apparently \maketitle calls \plainstyle, which overrides the fancyhdr settings. Is there a simple patch for this? In the following MWE, commenting and un-commenting line 34 totally changes the layout of the document. I want to preserve all the document characteristics with \maketitle commented out, with just the addition of the title section about the text columns. Any help?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

%..define packages to be used in controlling document features and layout  
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,bottom=2cm,top=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr, lipsum}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{titling}

\usepackage{etoolbox} %..http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199317/custom-footer-on-title-page-using-maketitle-and-book-document-class
\patchcmd{\maketitle}
  {\end{titlepage}}
  {\thispagestyle{titlepagestyle}\end{titlepage}}
  {}{}

%..This section controls the header-footer layout of the document
\setlength\headheight{25mm}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhead[L]{\parbox[b][10mm][t]{0.5\textwidth}{\large{COMPANY NAME HERE}}}
\fancyhead[R]{LOGO HERE}

\fancyfoot[C]{\textit{\textcopyright \,DRAFT: SOME COMPANY, \today}}

%..This section controls the title layout
\title{TITLE}
\author{NAME and ID}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

%\maketitle

\begin{multicols*}{2}

\section{First Section}

Hello, here is some text without a meaning.  This text should show what  a printed text will look like at this place. If you read this text, you will get no information.  Really?  Is there no information?  Is there...

\section{Second Section}

Hello, here is some text without a meaning.  This text should show what  a printed text will look like at this place. If you read this text, you will get no information.  Really?  Is there no information?  Is there...

\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As it stands, the bottom of your pages will disappear to Never, Never Land as soon as you get to the bottom of a column. This is because you change the value of `headheight` after `geometry` has done its magic.

If you include `headheight=25mm` in the options for `geometry`, the header is cut off because you have not allowed sufficient space. `top` cannot be smaller than the size you want for the header.

`article` does not use a `titlepage` by default so the patching has no effect. Since it uses an undefined page style, that may be just as well.

Here's a fixed version which maintains as much of your layout as possible subject to the constraint of everything fitting on the page. I use `showframe` to make the layout clearer.

`\thispagestyle{fancy}` is used after `\maketitle` to ensure the header and footer.

[image: fixed layout fits on page]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

%..define packages to be used in controlling document features and layout
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, bottom=2cm, top=25mm, marginparwidth=0pt, headheight=25mm, verbose, showframe]{geometry}% top must be at least headheight!
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr, lipsum}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{titling}

%..This section controls the header-footer layout of the document
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhead[L]{\parbox[b][10mm][t]{0.5\textwidth}{\large{COMPANY NAME HERE}}}
\fancyhead[R]{LOGO HERE}

\fancyfoot[C]{\textit{\textcopyright \,DRAFT: SOME COMPANY, \today}}

%..This section controls the title layout
\title{TITLE}
\author{NAME and ID}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

  \maketitle\thispagestyle{fancy}

  \begin{multicols*}{2}

    \section{First Section}

    \lipsum[1-10]

    \section{Second Section}

    \lipsum[11-20]

  \end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's helpful. As a bonus, do you have any tips on how to shrink the amount of whitespace between the header and the title?

Comment: @Aaron See the manual for `titling`. That lets you configure the layout of the title fairly easily.

Answer (score 1):

This is discussed on page 7 of fancyhdr documentation.  Just redefine the `plain` page style:

```
 \fancypagestyle{plain}{INSERT YOUR DEFINITIONS}
```

Comment: This is the easiest solution! I've searched for hours. If you stumble upon this and are also using `org-export` then you can simply add the line `#+LATEX_HEADER: \fancypagestyle{plain}{}` to the tree being exported and the title page will also have the header/footer defined with `fancyhdr`.