# Similar command addtobeamertemplate for articles and reports

Tags: templates

I have the following code in my beamer presentation:

```
\addtoreporttemplate{frametitle}{}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
    \node[anchor=south,yshift=5pt] at (current page text area.south) {\includegraphics[height=0.8cm,width=\linewidth]{images/logo}};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\title{My Presentation}
\author{me}
\date{
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
    \node[anchor=south,yshift=5pt] at (current page text area.south) {\includegraphics[height=0.8cm,width=\linewidth]{images/logo}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
```

What i want to know is if there is a similar command for reports/articles, etc, i.e., like:

```
\addtoreporttemplate{}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
    \node[anchor=south,yshift=5pt] at (current page text area.south) {\includegraphics[height=0.8cm,width=\linewidth]{images/logo}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
```

So that my logo would be added to everypage.

I tried using fancy header, but the logo isn't added to my cover page.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried with fancy header? If the logo is missing from the cover page, one probably just needs to set the pagestyle for this page, something along the lines of `\thispagestyle{fancy}`

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\includegraphics[height=0.8cm,width=\linewidth]{example-image}}

\title{bla}
\author{bla}

\usepackage{etoolbox} %..http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199317/custom-footer-on-title-page-using-maketitle-and-book-document-class
\patchcmd{\maketitle}
  {\end{titlepage}}
  {\thispagestyle{fancy}\end{titlepage}}
  {}{}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]